# Why does direct code quotation of System.Func yield a delegate and spliced quotation yields a lambda?

Tags: f#

I was surprised that the [direct code quotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/code-quotations)

```
<@ System.Func<int,int>( fun x -> x+1 ) @>
```

produces an `Expr.NewDelegate` and the [spliced code quotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/code-quotations#splicing-operators)

```
<@ fun x -> x+1 @> |> fun e -> <@ System.Func<int,int>( %e ) @>
```

produces an `Expr.Lambda`, I had assumed these expressions were equivalent.

Is that expected? Is there an explanation why?

Comment: I wonder if  the F# func gets inlined at compile time in the first example, but because its composed at runtime in the second the inlining doesn't happen.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato I think that is partly true, according to https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/11744#issuecomment-871777484 there is an "implicit conversion" for `Func<>`; my point is that I'd expect splicing _not_ to break the implicit conversion.

Comment: Now also raised with the maintainers in https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/11780